# No view updating after viewmodel been changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

can't find whats wrong and can't find answer anywhere. My problem is my view not updated after view model have bean changed

ViewModel:

```
public class OrderView
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DomenNames { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private OrderView ov;
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(ov);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderView model, FormCollection collection) {            
    return View("done");
}
public ActionResult BlankEditorRow(OrderView model) {
    ov = model;
    ov.Order.DomenNames.Add("");
    return View("Index",ov) ;
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Order",FormMethod.Post, new {id = "createOrder"})) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Order</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order.DomenNames)
    </div>

    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Order.DomenNames.Count; i++) {
        <div> 
            @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Order.DomenNames[i])
        </div>
    }

    <button type="button" id="b1" onclick="setallert()" >Click me</button>
 ...
```

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setallert() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Order/BlankEditorRow",
            data: $('#createOrder').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                ...?
            }
        });
    };    
</script>
```

it goes fine to pass model to controller and while debugging through view I can see that model is changed, but in some case it nothing happen in view. It looks like old model is in place.

Comment: You are doing an ajax post, but you are not doing anything to update the content in your view on success; you only have "*...?*" in the success callback. Are you asking: how to display the result of the ajax post?

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with javascript. It should in some way add new @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Order.DomenNames[i]) element.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Razor's Ajax helper, it's useful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using AJAX and not a full page postback? It looks like you want to display a completely different view, would you not be better just POSTing back and redirecting?

Comment: maybe i missing somthing, but I don't want use POSTback is validation on the ather fields... I don't want to do validation on that fields on this stage. Validation should be done on submit a form( it was not writen in "View" code)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I post my solution in case some one need it:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult BlankEditorRow(OrderView model) {
    model.Order.DomenNames.Add("");
    return PartialView("Index", model) ;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order.DomenNames)
</div>
<div id="tt">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("OrderDN", this.Model);}
</div>
<button type="button" id="addBtn">Click me</button>
```

Script:

```
$("#addBtn").click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("BlankEditorRow", "Order")', $('#createOrder').serialize(), function (res) {
        document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = res;
    });
})
```

I hope it will be useful to someone